# Flex - Detect word before EOF

Tags: c, regex, flex-lexer, eof

I'm working with Flex, and i need to do an acronym translator. I'm trying to detect a word just before of end of file, for example:

> OEA?
>
> OEA   ¿OEA?
>
> OEA

In this case, flex detect the first three acronym, but the last OEA doesn't translate. I have in the rules the next code:

```
%%

^OEA$ {fprintf(yyout,"Organizacion de los Estados Americanos");}
{START}OEA$ {fprintf(yyout,"%cOrganizacion de los Estados Americanos",yytext[0]);}
^OEA{END} {fprintf(yyout,"Organizacion de los Estados Americanos%c",yytext[yyleng-1]);}
{START}OEA{END} {fprintf(yyout,"%cOrganizacion de los Estados Americanos%c",yytext[0],yytext[yyleng-1]);}

%%
```

(START and END contains start and end delimiters, for example " " or ¿ ?)

I try using `OEA<<'EOF'>>`, but flex compiler shows `"unrecognized rule.."`

Somebody can help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Posix, a non-empty text file should always end with a newline character; files which end with an "Incomplete Line" are not, strictly speaking, text files and standard utilities which take text files as input are not required to handle the trailing Incomplete Line correctly. That's the theory, anyway.

In practice, it's not very easy to get a text stream which doesn't end with a newline. Most Unix utilities will add one unless explicitly told not to (the `-n` command line option to `echo`, for example, which is not Posix-standard). Many utilities provide no way to avoid the trailing newline (`sort` and `grep`, just off the top of my head).

None of that is much help to you if you want to handle such inputs correctly. It's more by way of an explanation of why it's annoyingly difficult to do in flex. In flex, `$` really means "followed by a newline character", and it is *exactly the same* as specifying trailing context, so these two patterns are identical:

```
OEA/"\n"
OEA$
```

Note that `/` is flex's "trailing context" operator, which afaik does not appear in any other regular expression language.

That differs from the `^` operator, which matches both the first character in the file and any character following a newline.

Your patterns can certainly be simplified by using the `/` operator; that will also allow you to recognize trailing strings, although it's a bit ugly:

```
^OEA/{END}       { fputs("Organización de Estados Americanos", yyout); }
^OEA             { fputs("Organización de Estados Americanos", yyout); }
{START}OEA/{END} { fputc(yytext[0], yyout);
                   fputs("Organización de Estados Americanos", yyout); }
{START}OEA       { fputc(yytext[0], yyout);
                   fputs("Organización de Estados Americanos", yyout); }
  /* These two patterns will match instead of the ones without trailing context,
   * because they are longer. The only way the patterns without trailing context
   * can match is if these don't match, which can only happen if the OEA is at
   * the end of a line or the end of the file.
   */ 
^OEA/.           { ECHO; }
{START}OEA/.     { ECHO; }
```